Apparent or real contradiction is in Eberlein's paper?
The questions I pose here concerns the paper "The Spin Model of Euclidean 3-Space" by W. F. Eberlein (The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 69, No. 7 (Aug. - Sep., 1962), pp. 587-598) (download or free online reading)
Since there is a typo in the paper just in the place I want to analyze, it's important to note that the second equation on page 597 shoud read as follows:
\begin{align}
i\hbar I\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}=& \left[\frac{1}{2m}\left(-i\hbar\nabla-\frac{e\mathfrak A}{c}\right)^2+e\Phi I\right]\psi\\=& \left[\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2+\frac{ie\hbar}{2mc}(\nabla\mathfrak A+\mathfrak A\nabla)+\left(\frac{e^2\mathfrak A^2}{2mc^2}+e\Phi I\right)\right]\psi
\end{align}
, that is, $\nabla\cdot\mathfrak A+\mathfrak A\cdot\nabla$ in the paper should read as $\nabla\mathfrak A+\mathfrak A\nabla$ in this equation (see Eberlein, W. F. “A Crucial Correction.” The American Mathematical Monthly 69, no. 10 (1962): 960–960. download or free online reading).

Background
The "spin model of the 3-dimensional Euclidean space" is the 3-dimensional Euclidean space $\frak E_3$ spanned by the
Pauli-matrices, i.e, it is the real vector space of the Hermitian and
traceless complex $2\times 2$ matrices. It is an Euclidean space with
respect to the scalar product $\cdot$ defined by the following
equation: $$\frac{1}{2}(AB+BA)=(A\cdot B)I\quad (A,B\in \mathfrak E_3)\tag 1$$ where $I$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. This
definition is based on the fact that for all $A, B \in\mathfrak E_3$,
$AB+BA = \delta_{ij}kI$, where $k$ is real. The positive definiteness
is ensured by the $\sigma_i\sigma_j+\sigma_2\sigma_i=\delta_{ij}I$
anticommutation relations of the Pauli matrices $\sigma_i$ and
$\sigma_j$. These commutation relations also show that Pauli matrices
form an orthonormal basis of $\mathfrak E_3$. An important property of
$\mathfrak E_3$ as a subset of $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb C)$ that
$$M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb C)=\mathrm{span}{(\{I\})}\oplus\mathfrak E_3\oplus i\mathfrak E_3\oplus i\,\mathrm{span}(\{I\}).\tag 2$$ In his
paper, Eberlein considers $\mathbb C^n$ endowed with the Hermitian
product $(x,y)=\sum_1^n x_j\overline y_j$ and denotes this Hermitian
space by $H_n$, while he regards $M_{n\times n}$ as the algebra of the
linear maps of $H_n$ to itself, and denotes it by $B(H_n)$.


Multiplications by differential operators
I restrict my question to the case a) of the paper, i.e. when $\psi:\mathfrak E_3\to \mathbb C$.
Taking an orthonormal base $\{\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3\}$ of $\mathfrak
 E_3$, Eberlein defines the symbol $\nabla$ only formally, as $\nabla =
 \xi_1\partial_1+\xi_2\partial_2+\xi_3\partial_3$ and $\nabla\psi$ as
$$\nabla\psi=\xi_1(\partial_1\psi)+\xi_2(\partial_2\psi)+\psi_3(\partial_3\psi)\tag i.$$  I guess he means the function $$\nabla\psi:\mathfrak E_3\to
 B(H_2):p\mapsto\partial_1\psi(p)\xi_1+\partial_2\psi(p)\xi_2+\partial_3\psi(p)\xi_3,\tag{ii}$$
that is, the value of $\nabla\psi$ at a point $p\in\mathfrak E_3$ is a
$2\times 2$ complex matrix with trace = $0$, or in other words, it is
an element of $\mathfrak E_3\oplus i\mathfrak E_3$.
Taking $\mathfrak A=\mathfrak A_1\xi_1+\mathfrak A_2\xi_2+\mathfrak A_3\xi_3\in\mathfrak E_3$ ($\mathfrak A_i\in\mathbb R$), the product
$\nabla\mathfrak A$ is the formal matrix product of $\nabla$ and
$\mathfrak A$, that is,
$$\nabla\mathfrak A=\sum_{i,j=1}^3\xi_i\partial_i\mathfrak A_j\xi_j\tag{iii}$$ where the $\xi_i$-s and $\xi_j$-s are regarded as $2 \times 2$ complex matrices, and the product $\mathfrak A\nabla$ is the formal
matrix product of $\mathfrak A$ and $\nabla$ , that is,
$$\mathfrak A\nabla=\sum_{i,j=1}^3\mathfrak A_j\xi_j\xi_i\partial_i\tag{iv},$$
while the product $\nabla\cdot\mathfrak A$ is the formal dot product
of $\nabla$ and $\mathfrak A$, that is,   $$\nabla\cdot\mathfrak
 A=\partial_1\mathfrak A_1+\partial_2\mathfrak A_2+\partial_3\mathfrak
 U_3\tag{v}$$  and $\mathfrak A\cdot \nabla$ is the formal dot product
of $\nabla$ and $\mathfrak A$, that is,  $$\mathfrak
 A\cdot\nabla=\mathfrak A_1\partial_1+\mathfrak A_2\partial_2+\mathfrak
 A_3\partial_3\tag{vi}$$

From the derivation of eq. (8) in the paper, one sees that according to the author, in an orthonormal basis $\{\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3\}$ of $\mathfrak E_3$,
$$\begin{align}\nabla \mathfrak A+\mathfrak A\nabla = & (\nabla \cdot \mathfrak A+\mathfrak A\cdot \nabla)I \\ & \color{red}{+i\left[\xi_1\{\partial_2\mathfrak A_3- \partial_3\mathfrak A_2\}+\xi_2\{\partial_3\mathfrak A_1- \partial_1\mathfrak A_3\}+\xi_3\{\partial_1\mathfrak A_2- \partial_2\mathfrak A_1\}\right]}. \end{align}\tag 3$$
Since every definition is formal, I would expect any identities of $\mathfrak E_3$ remain valid also for the formal $\nabla$ symbol too. (however, the comment by Kurt G. disproves my expectations ab ovo), so I would expect, according to (1), that
$$\nabla \mathfrak A+\mathfrak A\nabla = (\nabla \cdot \mathfrak A+\mathfrak A\cdot \nabla)I \tag 4.$$
As the calculations in the paper are very formal, I cannot say whether this is a real contradiction or an apparent one. Could someone please explain in clear mathematical terms the cause of the difference between (3) and (4)?

Not only the paper seems very formal, your post is it as well. Since the difference between $\nabla\mathfrak U$ and $\nabla\cdot\mathfrak U$ is that crucial and the dot appears prominently in (1) you may want to tell us what these multiplications are.

@KurtG. You are right, I will add the missing definitions as soon as I can.

Also note that not every vector identity holds when a vector is replaced by the differential operator $\nabla,.$ My favourite example is the Grassmann identity
$$
A\times(B\times C)=B(A\cdot C)-C(A\cdot B)
$$
also known as BAC-CAB-identity. With $B$ replaced by $\nabla$ and $C=A$ this becomes
$$
A\times(\nabla \times A)= {\color{red}{\frac 12}}\nabla(A \cdot A)-(A\cdot \nabla)A,.
$$

The quantum mechanical part of that paper seems just to be about the Pauli equation and its difference between the general form and the standard form. In the latter the spin term $q\hbar\boldsymbol{\sigma}\cdot\boldsymbol{B}$ is more visible. Better to understand this from another source and then perhaps return to Eberlein.

A large part of Eberlein's paper is devoted to showing that any right handed orthonormal basis $\zeta_1,\zeta_2,\zeta_3$ of $\mathfrak E_3$ is a set of complex $2\times 2$-matrices that satisfy the same (anti-)commutation relations as the Pauli matrices do: $\zeta_i\zeta_j+\zeta_j\zeta_i=2\delta_{ij}I$ and so on.
I am absolutely sure that this explains your equation (3).
